# EventListener change on multiple textfield

Tags: android, titanium, textfield, appcelerator-titanium

there are two textfield want to change value vice versa, try to do below-mentioned code but which is not working

```
var contnt = 10;

txtfld1.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
   e.source.value = parseFloat(txtfld1.value) - parseFloat(contnt);
});

txtfld2.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
       e.source.value = parseFloat(txtfld2.value) - parseFloat(contnt);
    });
```

Showing `NaN` while entering values in both textfields

can someone suggest any solution?

Comment: why are you parseFloating an object? `parseFloat(txtfld2)` should be `parseFloat(txtfld2.value)` i guess

Comment: @Flame that's not an issue. edited the question.

Comment: well it's obviously the `parseFloat` then which when it receives an incorrect string, will return `NaN`. In other words, `txtfld.value` is a string. `parseFloat('')` will return `NaN` while `parseFloat('15')` will return `15`.